# Define smartphones that not support SQLite

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I develop phonegap application, and use SQLite
Today i found that firefox not supports it, after additional investigation i found that also IE8 not supports
As i understood phonegap works on default system browser
From here my question, how user can to know that his smartphone will works with my application
Or how i can to know and say to users that my application will not works

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhoneGap **does NOT** use the default browser for rendering. It uses **WebKit** rendering engine on all the platforms it supports. So if you can get SQLite running on one platform with PhoneGap, it in the same way in all the platforms which supports PhoneGap. On a side note, Chrome and Safari uses WebKit as their rendering engine and so use these browsers to test your app on your desktop.